# How to move an attribute into another section en masse?

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, products, php-5.4

I have a product attribute in 'General' called 'download link' for example.

My goal is to move those values into the 'Additional Downloads' section, for each product.

[image]

I have started writing a PHP script for this with no luck.

**Is there an effective way to migrate attributes across sections, preferably programmatically?**

*NB: There are over 9000 products*

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to migrate them for each product. You only need to do it for each attribute set.
Go to Catalog->Attributes->Attribute Sets, edit each attribute set and drag and drop the attributes between sections.

Comment: The additional downloads section doesn't appear to be in my attribute sets?

Comment: This means that the `Additional Downloads` section does not contain product attributes. Most probably it is added there by a custom module. In this case you cannot move those attributes inside the section.

Comment: Not even programmatically?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. It's kind of hard to get and idea without knowing what that tab contains and how it was added to the product form. in general, only tabs util the 'inventory' tab (without it) contain product attributes. The rest of the tabs have different blocks and templates associated to them  and have other logic behind them

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do it non-programatically?

Export the data the 'dataflow' way with just sku and the two fields that correspond to your downloads and additional downloads, then rename the column headings in a spreadsheet, then upload it again, dataflow style?

This is a one time thing so, if dataflow works, give it a go.

You might need to put a test product together so you know that you are getting the fields right - test product could have 'from.pdf' and 'to.pdf' in the boxes you want to swap over - you can then check for these before doing your upload.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need create Additional Downloads group for each attribute set then  then move your attribute to this Group for going to each attribute set.

Suppose You have to Attribute Set `TestOne,TestTwo`  .Goto `Admin>Catalog>Attribute>Manage Attribute` set click on  this Attribute set `TestOne`. after on this attribute set ,You will fund a button group  button  Click on it and it will  new group  at this attribute set.

Now you will need to  `Download link` attribute this group.

Same is need to follow `TestTwo`  to attribute